# How can I show that $f(x) = \int_{x^2}^{x^4}e^{-t^2}dt$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

> Show that the function defined bellow is bounded 
>   $$f(x) =  \int_{x^2}^{x^4}e^{-t^2}dt\quad x\in\mathbb{R}$$

---

Since $e^{-t^2}$ is positive for any $t$ in $\Bbb R$ then I know that $f(x) > 0$ but I don't know how to find an upper bound of $f(x)$.

Comment: HINT: It is enough to show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$, and that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Be careful that $f(0)=0$ and $f(.5)<0$ be the convention of Riemann integral.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
0\leq |f(x)|\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2}\ dx=\sqrt{\pi}<\infty.
$$

where $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2}\ dx$ is the well known [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\int_{x^{2}}^{x^{4}}e^{-t^{2}}dt & \leq\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^{2}}dt & \text{(}e^{x}\text{ is nonnegative)}\\
 & =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2}}dt & \text{(substitute }t=u/\sqrt{2}\text{)}\\
 & =\sqrt{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2}}dt & \text{}\\
 & =\sqrt{\pi}&\text{(integrand is PDF of normal distribution)}
\end{align*}